# All requirements for a Vertical Scrollbar to show up: Why is it Hiding?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, vcl

What are all the requirements to make a vertical scrollbar to show up? It seems very random.

I tried:

```
HorzScrollBar.Range := 10000; // set the range to an higher number
VertScrollBar.Range := 10000; // set the range to an higher number
ShowScrollBar(Handle, SB_BOTH, True);
```

In combination with adjusting ranges in object inspector as well as AutoScroll on/off, client height (of the form). I think I had all combinations possible in the past hour. It seems like it doesn't matter what I do, the scrollbar is not coming back anymore - where it first showed up when I randomly re-adjusted some settings (to the same settings?).

What I am trying to accomplish: when I press a button the form shows up and should show on the right of the screen, with the following:

```
Form1.Height := Screen.Height - 40;
Form1.Left := Screen.Width - 423;
Form1.Show;
```

The form is an options menu, where all the options fit perfectly on the screen I am using now. However, I made a panel that will become longer (more height) and push all other options down when a certain option is clicked. So THEN is when I need that scrollbar, as settings start falling off the screen.

Ideally it would only show up when those options where clicked and disappear when it is no longer necessary, but somehow it is not showing up at all - it doesn't matter what sizes or ranges I give the form.

What other option I am forgetting to set/what other dependents AutoScroll or just VerticalScrollbar have in order to show up when needed?

---

With ShowMessage function I have some more information. I created a button which performed the following:

```
procedure TfrmInstellingenMenu.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
VertScrollBar.Visible := true;
ShowMessage('Visible? ' + BoolToStr(VertScrollBar.IsScrollBarVisible)); 
    //returns "Visible? -1". -1 is TRUE*, so yes (*tnx Ken)
ShowMessage('Autoscroll turned on? ' + BoolToStr(AutoScroll));
    //returns "Autoscroll turned on? 0". 0 is False, so no
ShowMessage('Range=' + IntToStr(VertScrollBar.Range));
    //returns "Range=8000". 
end;
```

So although the VertScrollbar is turned on, AutoScroll (because of that) is automatically turned off plus the range is by far enough, why is it still hiding?

Edit2:
Some more details:
It is a VCL form, borderstyle is set to bsSizable. In the form there are basically only 2 panels of the same size. They have both constrained sizes and are aligned to left and right at start. A button aligns them to Top and to Bottom. When I set the button to set them both to align to Top, it does not matter what I set the form Height anymore (probably cause of the constraints of the two panels). It becomes too high for my computer screen though and a part of the form disappears off the screen. When I set one to align to top and the other to Bottom the whole form is on the screen, but the two panels overlap each other. Ah, and offcourse still no scrollbar.

Comment: > *"form is an options menu"* > Dialog frame? VCL autoscroll works with sizeable border.

Comment: You're wrong. False is 0. If you use `BoolToStr(VertScrollBar.IsScrollBarVisible, True)` you'll see the correct values.

Comment: Is it possible that your options menu is within another container that does not enlarge accordingly?

Comment: The options menu is a VCL Form. In that Form there are basically 2 panels. All of the (bit)buttons, checkboxes and other stuff in this form are inserted in these two panels (mostly with other panels, so fe panel in panel in panel --> button). These two 'main' panels have constrained sizes and are aligned to Left and Right (at start). A button in this menu can set them both to align to Top, so the panels are placed above each other instead of next to each other. To get them aligned right I put constraints on the top, which also change when the button is clicked.

Comment: I understand that this limits the scrollbar (as the Form cannot create more width to place the scrollbar). But also when I enlarge the width of the Form  or put the Form constrains to 0, a scrollbar does not show up. I have not tried deleting the constrains from the two main panels, but I cannot imagine how that could or should make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

**AutoScroll on**

Setting `Autoscroll = true` the scrollbar appears when the extents of the components on the form exceed the forms client size, if

- border style is either `bsSizeable` (default) or `bsSizeToolWin`.
- and visibility is not prevented by setting `VertScrollBar.Visible = false`

**Note!** Changing border style in the IDE, and setting `Autoscroll = true`, brings up the scrollbar for any border style, but only in the IDE. This has possibly confused you.

**AutoScroll off**

Setting `VertScrollBar.Range` bigger than the client height of the form, brings up the scrollbar, regardless of `BorderStyle` and regardless of `Autoscroll` setting. In this case the visibility can be controlled with `VertScrollBar.Visible` as needed.

You did not say which border style you want to use, but if it is one of those that hides the scrollbar, you can also consider placing your controls on a `Scrollbox` with `Align = alClient`.

---

Edit after edit2 in question:

Your "Edit2" changed the context but I offer you to consider the following test I made with a form, two panels and a button. **To prevent the panels from overlapping (or leave a gap) in this context, you should set both panels to the same `Align`**. After changing `Align` (for horizontal/vertical) simply reset the forms height to what it should be. Explained after the code below.

Added following field to the form:

```
private
  Horizontal: boolean;
```

Constraints of `Panel1` and `Panel2`are set to 100, 150, 100, 150 (order as in OI)

Property `Align` of both panels is set to `alTop`. Form resizes to enclose the two panels.

Property `Form5.AutoScroll` is set to `True` and constraints of `Form5` are set to 180, 180, 0, 0. Note how the scrollbar is visible, growing the width of the form to make room.

Button is placed on `Panel1` and `OnClick` looks like this:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Horizontal := not Horizontal;
  if Horizontal then
  begin
    Panel2.Align := alLeft;
    Panel1.Align := alLeft;
  end
  else
  begin
    Panel1.Align := alTop;
    Panel2.Align := alTop;
    Constraints.MaxHeight := 180;  // set size of form back to what it should be
  end;
end;
```

The reason for resetting the forms height, is that during calculation of extents, the forms constraints are not respected. Dunno if as designed or not, but is anyway why your form floats over. Subsequently, setting the forms constraints at design time is not really needed.

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you, a seperate scrollbox in the form might work, but right now it messes up the form completely when I use the transform button (described in edit2 or in comment above). Will come back to this.

Comment: 2theEdit: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I am trying to set all the settings the same as with this example in my options menu. Did you notice that sometimes, when the H/V button is clicked, panel 2 is set above panel one, or panel 2 is set to the most left? At least when I followed these steps it happened, any idea how to prevent this (as setting one to the bottom and another to the top wont work). PS. the scrollbar on my menu form hasnt shown up yet but I'm sure there I'll figure it out soon with this example lol

Comment: @l3ob No, after I changed to set `Panel2.Align` first when changing to horizontal it never swaps their order. Neither for vertical. If it would happen, I would try setting both panels `Align` to `alNone` first and then the new align. For the vertical scrollbar I only set `AutoScroll  = True`. I believe I have answered your question about what affects the scrollbar visibility. If you have further questions regarding swapping orientations etc. please post a new question (they are free ;) )

Comment: @l3ob Sounds overly complicated and thus fragile to be easily managable, (as you have seen). I can't see how the components, held within those two panels can have any effect on how the forms scrollbar appear or disappear, unless you do something unforseeable in code.